# System.currenTimeInMillis() vs System.nanoTime()

Tags: java

I know that `System.nanoTime()` is now the preferred method for measuring time over `System.currentTimeInMillis()`  . The first obvious reason is nanoTime() gives more precise timing and the other reason I read that the latter is affected by adjustments to the system’s real-time clock. What does "getting affected by systems real-time clock " mean ?

Comment: I'm curious as well.  What would happen if you tried using `currentTimeInMillis()` to record elapsed time during a daylight savings time shift?  Or is that not what it means?

Comment: What `currentTimeMillis` tries to measure is the flow of time as a physical phenomenon. A DST shift is similar to a change in time zone when you travel: it only affects how time is represented in hours and minutes; time itself is not affected.

Comment: `currentTimeMillis` isn't affected by e.g. DST, but it is affected by e.g. leapseconds and the like, unlike `nanoTime`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman from the blog mentioned in platzhirsch's  answer "This is a problem because events related to absolute time need to be aware of changes in absolute time ( eg the start/end of daylight savings time), while relative times should be immune to such changes. Invariably this means that there are problems (one way or the other) on most operating systems. " and since `currentTimeInMillis` uses the "time of the day" or absolute clock , doesn't it imply that currentTimeInMillis is affected by DST ?

Comment: @JoniSalonen please see my comment to Louis . What is your take on that ?

Comment: `currentTimeMillis` measures the time that has passed since Jan 1 1970 00:00 UTC. What happens in a DST shift is that the wallclock time is adjusted: e.g. one second after 00:59:59 the wall clock time is 02:00:00. But since only one second passed, the value of `currentTimeMillis` should be seen to incerement by one second only, not by one hour one second.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In this case I've found following blog post excerpt useful:

> If you are interested in **measuring absolute time** then always use
>   `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Be aware that its resolution may be quite
>   coarse (though this is rarely an issue for absolute times.)
>
> If you are interested in **measuring/calculating elapsed time**, then
>   always use `System.nanoTime()`. On most systems it will give a
>   resolution on the order of microseconds. Be aware though, this call
>   can also take microseconds to execute on some platforms.

[Clocks and Timers - General Overview](https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks) by David Holmes

Since `System.currentTimeMillis()` is relying on the systems *time of day* clock, adjustments to the time are legitimate, in order to keep it on time.

What means adjustments here? Take for instance a look at the description of `CLOCK_REALTIME` from Linux:

> System-wide clock that measures real (i.e., wall-clock) time.
>                 Setting this clock requires appropriate privileges.  This clock is
>                 **affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time** (e.g., **if the
>                 system administrator manually changes the clock**), and by the
>                 incremental adjustments performed by adjtime(3) and NTP.

Comment: This is from the link you provided "The relative-time clock is represented by the System.nanoTime() method that returns a "free-running" time in nanoseconds. " Why is it called "free-running" time ?

Comment: @Geek I would say free, in means of *independent*. The absolute time depends on interrupts triggered by the operating system. The relative *free-running* time is independent of that, and as Joni Salonen has pointed out, derived from the internal CPU clock timer.

Comment: "Systems typically have both an absolute clock (the time-of-day clock, with a low resolution) and a relative clock (some kind of "high-resolution" counter from which a "free-running" time can be calculated). Why does time of the day clock have a low resolution and the relative one has a high resolution ?

Comment: Because, for instance, the CPU time stamp counter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) is far more precise, since it is roughly speaking incremented after every internal processor clock cycle. The frequency of a repeated interrupt signal is a lot lower.

Answer (score 8):

Just check the JavaDoc of the methods:

`System.nanoTime()`

"... This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. ..."

`System.currentTimeMillis()`

"... Returns the current time in milliseconds. ..."

So as you can see if the system time changes during the measurement using the `System.currentTimeMillis()`, the interval you measure will change too. However, it will not change when measuring the interval using the `System.nanoTime()` method.

Answer (score 6):

It means that the value that `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns is obtained from the internal clock of the machine. If a sysadmin (or NTP) changes the time, for example if the clock is found to be running 5 minutes fast and the sysadmin goes and corrects it, `System.currentTimeMillis()` will be affected. This means that you can even see the value decrease, and if you use it to measure intervals the timings can be off. You may even measure *negative* timings.

`System.nanoTime()` on the other hand returns a value that is derived from some internal CPU counter/clock. The time measured by this clock cannot be changed by any user or program. This means that it will be more reliable for timing. But the CPU clock is reset on poweroff so it's not useful for finding the current "wall-clock" time.